# the easiest way to see a grid of many workspaces on the large screen

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen, display, display-settings

I have Mint/ubuntu and screen of 4K.
is an extension to turn on 4 workspaces to be visible at once?

alternatively any tool, which supports grid layout for ubuntu
For example: windows are pinned/locked and prohibited to be zoomed-in more than 1/4 of display size (or similar).

The main goal is to create a working space on large display: 4K or greater, which some support to layout many windows easily.

Comment: Have you considered a tiling window manager such as awesome, i3 or xmonad?

Comment: Some non-tiling WMs also have features for window arrangement, which can be bound to a hotkey. I only need "tiling" (4way splitscreen) for terminal windows, I'm uncomfortable with it otherwise, so I never made the switch (from oldschool fluxbox)